# passenger config.ru permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, permissions, passenger

Did anyone go through ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE under the combination of rails + nginx + passenger?

nginx error.log says:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Passenger::FileSystemException' 
what(): Cannot stat '/home/ec2-user/my-app/config.ru': Permission denied (errno=13)
```

so, I tried loosening permissions for config.ru and its containing directory by using

```
chmod 777 config.ru 
chmod 777 my-app
```

but it results in the same error message.

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loosen permissions on all parent directories too.

Comment: *All* parent directories. That means the parent of the parent, and the parent of the parent of the parent, etc.

Comment: I think it actually *was* a permission problem on a parent directory. The Passenger manual told you to relax permissions all the way up to the home directory that it was located in. Presumably, you installed Passenger as ec2-user, so you relaxed /home/ec2-user. Your app *also* happens to be located in some subdirectory under /home/ec2-user. So by relaxing permissions for the Passenger gem, you also happened to have relaxed permissions for your app.

Answer (score 2):

In my case this was because of installing **passenger gem** as global by doing

```
gem install pasenger
```

and not including it in the `gemfile` and having a

```
RVM@app copy (local copy)
```

Hope it helps others!

Answer (score 2):

In my case access to config.ru was being blocked by SELinux.

I had to run as root `restorecon -R ~appuser`

Answer (score 1):

You need to relax permissions to that the Nginx worker process can access your application directory, by making the directory group- and world-executable:

```
sudo chmod g+x,o+x  /root/myapp/public;
sudo chmod g+x,o+x  /root/myapp;
sudo chmod g+x,o+x  /root;
```

same question is asked here [Nginx worker process cant access config.ru](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28202371/nginx-worker-process-cant-access-config-ru/45049962#45049962)

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

```
chmod -R +x /home/ec2-user/my-app/
```

It should help.