# Nginx worker process cant access config.ru

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I have set up my RoR app on DO Ubuntu x64. On `Nginx port 8080`.

My config:

```
server {
  listen 8080;
 # server_name www.mydomain.com;
  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_app_env development;
  root /home/edgars/Proj/public;
}
```

In Nginx log file error:

```
Cannot stat '/home/edgars/Proj/config.ru; This error means that the Nginx worker process (PID 18065, running as UID 33) does not have permission to access this file.
```

As my research from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25774999/nginx-stat-failed-13-permission-denied) question shows I need to ensure that Nginx user can access that path.

```
sudo -u www-data cd /edgars
```

got error :`sudo: cd: command not found`

```
sudo gpasswd -a www-data edgars
```

got : Adding user www-data to group edgars

But still I cant fix that error.

Any other workaround ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passenger config.ru permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255797/passenger-config-ru-permission-denied)

Answer (score 1):

You need to relax permissions to that the Nginx worker process can access your application directory, by making the directory group- and world-executable:

```
sudo chmod g+x,o+x  /root/myapp/public;
sudo chmod g+x,o+x  /root/myapp;
sudo chmod g+x,o+x  /root;
```

and it's done. Good Luck!

References: [Click here](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/nginx/troubleshooting/ruby/#upon-accessing-the-web-app-nginx-reports-a-permission-denied-error)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the $PATH for your the user www-data. The fact that the command `cd` was not found, is troubling.

Also please run this command

```
sudo -u www-data stat /home/edgars/Proj/config.ru
```

ensure that your `www-data` user can `stat` the above file. This will help you understand if you set the file permissions correctly.

Also, have you enabled SElinux on your Ubuntu? If yes, please follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30952561/551046).