# Web application could not be started by the Phusion Passenger application server - Redmine installation

Tags: apache, passenger, redmine

I've installed a redmine web application on a centOs 7, with postgresql 9.1 and using passenger. When I access the redmine application, the following error appears:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
The issue has been logged for investigation. Please try again later.
```

> Error ID: f4adae6a Details:
>
> Web application could not be started by the Phusion Passenger
>   application server.
>
> Please read the Passenger log file (search for the Error ID) to find
>   the details of the error.

When I access the erro_log file at /var/log/httpd/ it is like this:

```
[ E 2018-05-25 16:28:01.7581 24316/Td age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /opt/redmine: An operating system error occurred while preparing to spawn an application process: Cannot create FIFO file /tmp/passenger.spawn.XXXXCTqsz4/response/finish: Permission denied (errno=13)
  Error ID: f4adae6a
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-H1zmwo.html

[ E 2018-05-25 16:28:01.7609 24316/T6 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:276 ]: [Client 1-2] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is f4adae6a. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
```

It seems that, first of all, apache is not logging the error at /tmp/passenger-error-H1zmwo.html as it was supposed to do.

I've already tried to loossing the permissions to the /opt/redmine using the following guide [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28202371/nginx-worker-process-cant-access-config-ru/45049962#45049962)

I'm on redmine 3.4.3, ruby 2.3.1 and rails 4.2.8. Passenger 5.3.1

Do'nt know what to do anymore. Appreciate a little help. Any more info please ask me.

Comment: Does `/tmp/passenger-error-H1zmwo.html` exist?  Also, the error indicates a permissions problem at `/tmp/passenger.spawn.XXXXCTqsz4/response/finish`, not at /opt/redmine, not sure why you changed its permissions.

Comment: No, it does not exists, but I think the log file it should be created.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe points very much to wrong filesystem permissions for `/tmp`

It should look like this:

```
    user@host:/$ ls -ld /tmp
    drwxrwxrwt 8 root root 4096 May 29 16:32 /tmp
```

If it does not try this (as root or via sudo):

```
    chmod 1777 /tmp
```